# Find factorial Using call by reference function in C++

Tags: c++

I am missing very minor thing here i could not figure it out, i am just try to get the factorial of the number inputted, using a recursive call by reference concept in C++.
Please let me know what am i missing. Declaring few additional variables for more further alterations in programs.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int factorial(int &m);
int factorial(int &m)
{
    int i,result=0;
    
    
    if(m>=1)
    return  m * factorial(m-1);
    else
        return 0;

}

int main(){

    int m,i,factorial1=1;
    
    cout<<"Please enter the number to factor   "<<std::endl;
    cin>>m;
    factorial1=factorial(m);

    cout<<"Factorial value is " << factorial1<<std::endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Getting error as below

```
factorial_func.cc: In function ‘int factorial(int&)’:
factorial_func.cc:33:25: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int&’ to an rvalue of type ‘int’
   33 |  return m * factorial((m-1));
      |                       ~~^~~
factorial_func.cc:27:20: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int factorial(int&)’
   27 | int factorial(int &m)
      |               ~~~~~^
```

Comment: The result of `m - 1` is an *rvalue*, and lvalue-references (which `int &m` is) can't be bound to such values. Use e.g. `const int &m` instead. Or since `m` isn't modified, just pass it by value instead.

Comment: Another problem: if `m == 0`, the function should return 1, not 0

Comment: why do you pass `m` by reference?

Comment: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The errors in your program:**

1. It tries to bind a non-constant `lvalue` (roughly it means a variable that could be assigned in the left hand side of `=` sign) reference of type an integer reference (from argument) to an `rvalue` of an integer in the syntax:

   ```
   return  m * factorial(m - 1);
   ```
2. Passing a reference is not required here at all. You may remove `&`.
3. The `else` statement returns a zero instead of one when the `m` is lesser than 1 and that gives you unexpected output since any multiplication operation with a zero is always a zero.

**You should try:**

1. Returning an integer from the argument directly rather than returning a reference value.
2. You must return `1` instead of `0` when `m` reaches lesser than 1 in the `else` condition.
3. The variables declared in `factorial()` are totally unused and redundant and `i` is unused in `main()`.

---

**Code redefined:**

```
#include <iostream>

int factorial(int param) {
    if (param >= 1)
        return param * factorial(param - 1); // new * (-1 than new) recursively
    else
        return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int fact = 1;
    int num;

    std::cout << "Please enter the number to factor: ";
    std::cin >> num;

    fact = factorial(num);

    std::cout << "Factorial is: " << fact << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After fixing the errors, you'll get output like:

```
$ g++ -o prog prog.cpp; ./prog
Please enter the number to factor: 5 // --- INPUT
Factorial is: 120 // --- OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1):

Dude's answer is correct, there is no need to apply an lvalue ref as argument, a pass by (r)value is correct, this applies as general advice for recursive functionality to avoid side effects.
More serious is a fault: factorial of 0 is not 0, but by definition it is 1 !!!
Whether this sounds illogical, see the discussion on https://www.quora.com/Why-does-zero-factorial-0-equal-one-1-1

@Dorian: It's easy to spare 2 recursive calls by tackling the factorials of 0 1 2:

```
int factorial(int m)
{
    if (m > 2)
        return  m * factorial(m - 1);
    else if (m == 0)
        m = 1;
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your working code.
Some tipps:

1. [why not use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
2. You need to pass 1 in the last factorial, otherwise your result is multiplied by 0 and that's 0, so it won't work
3. if you only pass single `int`s, you can pass them easier by value (gives you less problems in the beginning).
   BUT: in any case passing by reference here is wrong, because you don't want the original value to change, but in recursion you want to have a RETURN value.
4. regarding you original error: you are trying to bind an *rvalue* (a value that stands ONLY on the right side of an equation) to an *lvalue* reference (`&m`), which you cannot do, since if you are changing the *lvalue* reference, you cannot change the right side of the equation. You can use *rvalue* references (`&&m`), but this is quite advance `C++` and you should maybe read up [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) first to get an idea of what you are dealing with.

```
#include <iostream>
int factorial(int m);
int factorial(int m)
{    
    if (m >= 1)
       return  m * factorial(m-1);
    else
       return 1;

}

int main(){

    int m, factorial1 = 1;
    
    std::cout << "Please enter the number to factor" <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> m;
    factorial1=factorial(m);

    std::cout<<"Factorial value is " << factorial1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```